# applying conditional formating formula to a cell in inserted row (invalid procedure call/argument run-time error 5)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to apply a conditional formatting formula to a second column of an inserted row. The cell in column B in inserted row will change color if user enters text into that cell (if a cell is not blank)

The following code produces run-time error '5' (invalid procedure call/argument).

Thank you,

```
Public Sub insertNewRow(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim thisWs As Worksheet, thisRow As Range, l As Double, r As Double, i As Long
    Dim tr As Long

    'setColors
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set thisWs = ActiveSheet
    Set thisRow = Target
    tr = thisRow.Row
    If tr > 2 Then

        With Target.Cells(1, 2)
            .Select
            Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=(NOT(ISBLANK($B2))"
           Selection.FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = lBlu

            Target.Cells(1, 1).Value = Target.Cells(0, 1).Value 'copy down RunID/SampleID from row above
            With Target.Cells(1, 4)
                .Value2 = "New variant in row " & tr   'insert "New data" in first cell of current row
                .Interior.Color = vbYellow

            End With

        End With
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count).Activate
        thisWs.Activate 
        thisWs.Cells(1, 1).Select
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: your formula is always pointing to cell B2, so if you add text in B2 does it apply the formatting?

Comment: no, it doesn't apply anything

Comment: Replace your formula with: Formula1:="=NOT(ISBLANK(B2))"

Comment: @Sorceri, Do you know how to change the formula so it looks in the inserted row in column B to see if there is a value there, not at in B2? Obviously, it will be blank at first but later the user will add text and I need the color to change. Your suggested code works for B2 scenario. Thank you

Comment: Try `Target.Cells(1, 2)` instead of `B2`? (Not sure what range that computes to though XD) You'd have to concat it with `&`. Also, you don't need `.select/selection`.

Comment: I've tried this: `With Target.Cells(1, 2)
       
          .Select
           Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=NOT(ISBLANK(B & Target.Cells(1, 2)))"
                     Selection.FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = lBlu` and it colors the new row cell at B blue even though it's blank? I'm not sure why.

Comment: Also please suggest something to get rid of the horrible screen flickering when a new row is inserted.  Or I will need a disclaimer for epileptic seizures :0

Comment: You need to break it up like how @Sorceri did below. Regarding flicker, do `application.screenupdating=false`.

Comment: I've already tried Application.ScreenUpdating = False but it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula was the first issue and then to set the range use the target address

```
Public Sub insertNewRow(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim thisWs As Worksheet, thisRow As Range, l As Double, r As Double, i As Long
    Dim tr As Long

    'setColors
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set thisWs = ActiveSheet
    Set thisRow = Target
    tr = thisRow.Row
    If tr > 2 Then

        With Target.Cells(1, 2)
           .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=NOT(ISBLANK(" & Target.Address & "))"
           .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = lBlu

            Target.Cells(1, 1).Value = Target.Cells(0, 1).Value 'copy down RunID/SampleID from row above
            With Target.Cells(1, 4)
                .Value2 = "New variant in row " & tr   'insert "New data" in first cell of current row
                .Interior.Color = vbYellow

            End With

        End With
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count).Activate
        thisWs.Activate
        thisWs.Cells(1, 1).Select
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added '.' to FormatContions and it works.

Comment: @user3781528  sorry about that, removed that in haste. Updated the post to reflect.    Don't forget to mark it as answered.